# Laravel change momentary route url from search to another url

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a searching bar in my learn project. I include it to the navbar.blade.php and when testing that it becomes that url construction.

```
localhost:8890/home?_token=7dKh256Me65Wb0rCvlJWkkk1SKdGrpaRPFCHP7MW&_method=GET&search=test
```

But the controller isn´t calling. I need this url to make it work:

```
localhost:8890/search?_token=7dKh256Me65Wb0rCvlJWkkk1SKdGrpaRPFCHP7MW&_method=GET&search=test
```

My route:

```
Route::get('search', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'search'])->name('search');
```

ProductController:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    //Get the search vale from the request
    $search = $request->input('search');

    $products = Product::query()
            ->where('ean', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('manufacturer', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('productNumber', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('propertie', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->get();

    return view('products.search',compact('products'));
}
```

Included navbar-search.blade.php

```html
<!-- Right navbar links -->
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <!-- Navbar Search -->
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="navbar-search" role="button">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-search-block">
            <form class="form-inline">
                @csrf
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control form-control-navbar" placeholder="Search" required>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <form action="{{route('search')}}" method="GET">
                            @csrf
                            @method('GET')
                            <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                        <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="button" data-widget="navbar-search">
                            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You dont need CSRF for GET method.
So... You don't need to add `@csrf` and `@method('GET')`.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Sharma in the comments before, you shouldn't use 2 form nested. Controller isn´t calling because first form doesn't set action.  You can edit it like this:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <!-- Navbar Search -->
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="navbar-search" role="button">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-search-block">
            <form class="form-inline" action="{{route('search')}}" method="GET">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control form-control-navbar" placeholder="Search" required>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="button" data-widget="navbar-search">
                            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```